# change font size in second display only in Gnome

Tags: linux, debian, fonts, gnome, debian-bookworm

I have got a second display connected to my laptop which has got resolution 3840 x 2160, my laptop has got only 1920 x 1080. The font which is OK on my laptop is way too small on the second display. Is it possible to configure bigger font size only for the other display in Gnome? I'm using Debian Bookworm and Gnome 43.9.

Comment: Try asking your question in Bing AI.  It says you can have different resolutions in Windows.  See if any of it applies to Gnome.